# Why Flutter Streambuilder widget ( onAuthStateChanged ) object give red underline?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I have imported all the dependencies and packages from firebase in my flutter app :

[image: screenshot]

Comment: When you hover your cursor on the red line, what does the error say?

Comment: The getter 'onAuthStateChanged' isn't defined for the type 'FirebaseAuth'.
Try importing the library that defines 'onAuthStateChanged', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'onAuthStateChanged'.

Comment: But i have imported all the packages and dependencies in my project

Comment: Checkout my answer.

Comment: Please edit the question and add more details  ( code as snippet not as an image, and what are the error messages you got ..

Answer (score 2):

The method `onAuthStateChanged` is now [authStateChanges](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/authStateChanges.html) in the version you're using.

You need to change the code from:

```dart
FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged
```

to:

```dart
FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges
```